# GXT Attached / Rendered

Tags: gxt

I have a GXT ContentPanel instance (cp). I attempt to add a Text object to the content panel as below:

```
Text text = new Text("Main Content Window");
cp.add(text);
```

However, the Text is not visible even though I did text.setVisible(true).  In my debugger, I saw that the content panel  (cp) does have the text object added to the cp.items list. However, the text object has "rendered = false" and "attached = false".

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may add the text to ContentPanel using Label which is straight forward.

by the way text is not not component to add to the panel(Contentpanel/ layout container)
we can add only component to the container.

Answer (score 0):

If ContentPanel is already rendered and you add anything to it you have to call cp.layout() to add new contents to the DOM. If you add the text before rendering it it's not necessary.